# parse String to Date on servlet (EJB3, Jboss)

Tags: java, servlets

First of all, please forgive my poor english.
I want to search like SendDate on my feedback form, but it don't work, it said it can't parse string to date.
Here is my code:
1.Session bean:

```
public Group3KSC.Feedback[] searchLikeSendDateFeedback(Date senddate) {
        try {
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Feedback f WHERE f.sendDate LIKE :sendDate");
            query.setParameter("sendDate", "%" + senddate + "%");
            List list = query.getResultList();
            Feedback[] result = new Feedback[list.size()];
            list.toArray(result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Search form:

```
 <form action="../AdminSearchSendDateServlet" method="post">
            <div> Search <input type="text" name="dbSearch" class="text-input datepicker"/>
                <p class="button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" name ="action"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

AdminSearchSendDateServlet (The Problem is here, when I declare searchsenddate)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        AdminSessionBeanLocal local = (AdminSessionBeanLocal) ctx.lookup("AdminSessionBeanLocalJNDI");
        if (action.equals("Search")) {

            SimpleDateFormat fBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date searchsenddate = fBirth.parse(request.getParameter("dbSearch").trim());
            Feedback[] u = local.searchLikeSendDateFeedback(searchsenddate);
            session.setAttribute("Username", u);
            response.sendRedirect("Admin/FeedbackList.jsp");
        }
```

ex: this record in database is:2014-05-25 00:00:00.000, when I search it in search form with date picker, it will input 05/25/2014, and when I'm click search button, it show those error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any compilation error in your code somewhere in `searchLikeSendDateFeedback()` method.

Comment: Is it the correct SQL query `SELECT f FROM Feedback f WHERE` where f is used as select and table alias name.

Comment: no, there is no error, the SQL is correct

Comment: At what line no you are getting this exception?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat fBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date searchsenddate = fBirth.parse(request.getParameter("dbSearch").trim());
at this i think,since the error said string cannot be cast to date

Comment: it happen on the AdminSearchSendDateServlet

Comment: No these lines will not cause the issue. It's some where else in the code.

Comment: Are you sure you can use a `LIKE` sentence in SQL for `date`/`time`/`datetime`/`timestamp` fields? I guess it is only for `char`/`varchar` fields.

Comment: Ah sorry, thanks for your help.Yes, it like all of you said,I can't use search Like on datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'sendDate' on DB is a Date columns? Have you tried pass the 'senddate' param as a date object instead of a string?

I hope it help.

Comment: ah thanks for your reply, the sendDate on DB is datetime columns.
Sorry but can you give me an example about pass the "senddate" param as date object? , I dont have much experience about it.

Comment: @NguyenTrongNhan In fact, you must not use LIKE on date or date times unless you convert the date column to string (e.g. DATEFORMAT(datetime_expression, format_string) in Sybase for example). 

You have to figure out what exactly you want to do. What pattern senddate param will carry? Month/Year?

It could be solved by converting/formating the date column just like above to extract just Month/Year. So you will can compare with just an equal (=).

Something like this: "SELECT f FROM Feedback f WHERE . DATEFORMAT(f.sendDate,'mm/yyyy') = :sendDate", using Sybase as an example.